# CSS media queries image loading

Tags: css, media-queries

I am currently looking to load a different background image based on the browser width. To reduce bandwidth, I would like for only the image I am going to show to be loaded.

I know it is possible to get this result using HTML with the picture tag.

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
    <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

In this example, only the appropriate image would be loaded. I.E: If the browser is wider than 650px, the pink flowers would be loaded. If the browser is between 465px and 650px, the white flowers would be loaded. Otherwise, the orange flowers would be loaded.

But using the `<picture>` tag does not seem like the appropriate solution since it should not be used to cover the whole screen.

Since I am working with a background image, I would like to set my image with the CSS property `background-image` on my body. I.E:

```
body {
    background-image: url("my-large-image.png");
}
```

Here's what I have right now:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("my-small-image.png");
    }
}
@media (max-width: 999px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("my-large-image.png");
    }
}
```

My question is: In my last example, are both images loaded or only the one with the appropriate size? If both images are loaded, how would you change it so that only the appropriate background image is loaded?

Comment: Did you try it and see for yourself?

Comment: I did. That's why I answered my own question after posting it. I wanted to leave a trace so someone could Google and get their answer instead of making a demo to get the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using media queries, only the appropriate image is loaded.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qg1xz52n/

On page load, only the first image is loaded. When resizing the browser, the second image is loaded. This behavior has been confirmed in Chrome and IE.

Code here:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Background image demo </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Background image demo </h1>
<style>
    @media (min-width: 1000px) {
        body {
            background-image: url("http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/5100000/Cats-wallpaper-cats-5194935-1280-1024.jpg");
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 999px) {
        body {
            background-image: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/cat-pattern-kitten-paw-background-vector-id1008277944");
        }
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using JavaScript instead of CSS? Because if you use JavaScript you would only have to add an event listener into the window, get the inner width and change the background image of the body based on the width.

```
window.addEventListener("resize",function(){
windowWidth = window.innerWidth
  if(windowWidth >= 1000){
  // Do Something
  }else if (windowWidth < 1000){
  // Do Something 
  }
});
```

Here's an example I did on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REGXbv?editors=1111). Also, checkout this reference from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_background.asp)

Comment: There seems to be some stuff missing in order to make this a working solution. First, you need to set up the image explicitly when the page is loaded (because the resize event is not triggered). Second, you need to have a flag to know which background is shown at the moment so you don't overwrite the background with the exact same background. I've created a CodePen with those changes: https://codepen.io/Thuranel/pen/BvQvVN

I believe the CSS only solution is a lot more simple.